# Camel body empty after sending to HTTP

Tags: java, apache-camel

Using the HTTP component, Camel seems to replace the body with the HTTP response body.  I want to log the body I sent **after** sending it.  The following with `streamCaching()` doesn't work and seems to be replaced with the response body:

```
from("direct:in")
    .streamCaching()
    .to("https://myEndpoint")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG, EVENT_SENT_MARKER, "body - ${body}")
```

Also tried `ignoreResponseBody`.  Same result:

```
from("direct:in")
    .streamCaching()
    .to("https://myEndpoint?ignoreResponseBody=true")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG, EVENT_SENT_MARKER, "body - ${body}")
```

Finally, since Camel's documentation says it sets `exchange.out`'s body with the http response body, I tried `${in.body}` with the same result:

```
from("direct:in")
    .streamCaching()
    .to("https://myEndpoint?ignoreResponseBody=true")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOG, EVENT_SENT_MARKER, "body - ${in.body}")
```

Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the bod in an header, something like:

```java
from("direct:in")
    .streamCaching()
    .setProperty("MyBody").body()
    .to("https://httpbin.org/post")
    .log("${exchangeProperty.MyBody}")
```

So you can have access to the body you sent and the answer from your service.

Comment: Wouldn't that result in the body header being setting to the HTTP endpoint?

Comment: yes but that was just to give an example, you can copy to a property which is not taken into account or use a custom header filter strategy

Comment: What do you mean by copying to a property that isn't taken into account?  Can you show that?

Comment: I meant to store the value in the exchange's properties that are not sent over the wire. So .setProperty("MyBody").body() instead of .setHeader("MyBody").body()

Comment: Oh, okay I'll accept your answer if you want to change it to that